# cannot run vendor/bin/homestead make getting error yaml.php line 52

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, homestead

I'm trying to install laravel/homestead and gettiong this error

```
HP@carlas MINGW64 /c/vagrant-Laravel (master)
$ vendor/bin/homestead make
PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in C:\vagrant-Laravel\vendor\symfony\yaml\Yaml.php on line 52

Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in C:\vagrant-Laravel\vendor\symfony\yaml\Yaml.php on line 52
```

I'm running Laravel Homestead 8.3.1 and as i have php 5.6 locally im emulating php 7 in my composer.json file so previously i ran

```
composer config platform.php 7.2
composer update phpunit/phpunit --ignore-platform-reqs
```

and then

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
ls laravel/bin/homestead
vendor/bin/homestead
```

and the last one

```
vendor/bin/homestead make
```

where i'm getting the error

I'm in windows 10 if it matters

Comment: Can you post your `Homestead.yaml` or copy & paste it into an online yaml linter to check if it's valid?

Comment: It looks like due to your platform config you are getting the Symfony Yaml component in version 4 which makes use of scalar type hints that are not compatible with the PHP 5 version you are using when executing `vendor/bin/homestead make`. I guess you either need to make sure that the code is executed with PHP 7 or install dependencies that are compatible with your PHP version.