# where should I put Homestead folder?

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm beginner user of Laravel. And I want to set up Homestead. but I don't know where should I put "Homestead" folder. It must be put in the project folder?

I'm trying Homestead setting tutorial on the official site in Japanese.

https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/homestead.html

And...

git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead

I don't know where directory should I go and execute this command.

Answer (score 0):

It will create a Homestead directory for you. It depends on you where you want to have it. It can be in root of C or in C:\Users\your_name.

Comment: Thank you for your replaying and your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the "Per-Project installation" for it is much more easy to get going with it.

1. Install vagrant
2. Look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#per-project-installation

Comment: I'll check it out and i'll try it.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I am trying the tutorial you suggested to me, but I am stuck. Here is a link on the exact same issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824538/cannot-run-vendor-bin-homestead-make-getting-error-yaml-php-line-52

Especially this command. It does not work.
vendor/bin/homestead make 

However, no one has answered since 4 months ago.
Anyway, thank you for answering the question.

Comment: Are your running the latest vendors? Make a `composer update` and retry, seems like an outdated version of yaml